# About SQL pivot table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to figure out how to produce this result in SQL using pivot table Sorted by SubID

| units | Sub | SubCode | AM | PM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Math | M2201 | Monday / 7:00AM-8:00AM | Tuesday / 1:00PM-2:00PM |
| 3 | Science | S2203 | Monday / 9:00AM-10:00AM | Tuesday / 3:00PM-4:00PM |
| 3 | Comp (lab) | C2203 | Friday / 9:00AM-10:00AM | Wednesday / 3:00PM-4:00PM |
| 2 | Comp (lec) | C2203 | Thursday / 9:00AM-10:00AM Friday / 7:00AM-8:00AM | Tuesday / 3:00PM-4:00PM |

Originally, I have 3 tables where I pull out data.

table SetSub

| ssID | AY | Prog | YLev | Sem | SubCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-2023 | Intermediate | 3 | 2 | M2201 |
| 2 | 2022-2023 | Intermediate | 3 | 2 | S2203 |
| 2 | 2022-2023 | Intermediate | 3 | 2 | C2203 |

table Sched

| schedID | Prog | Sem | SubCode | Sub | Units | Shift | SubType | Day | Sched | isLecLab |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Intermediate | 2 | M2201 | Math | 3 | AM | Lec | Monday | 7:00AM-8:00AM | 0 |
| 2 | Intermediate | 2 | M2201 | Math | 3 | PM | Lec | Tuesday | 1:00PM-2:00PM | 0 |
| 3 | Intermediate | 2 | S2203 | Science | 3 | AM | Lec | Monday | 9:00AM-10:00AM | 0 |
| 4 | Intermediate | 2 | S2203 | Science | 3 | PM | Lec | Tuesday | 3:00PM-4:00PM | 0 |
| 5 | Intermediate | 2 | C2203 | Comp | 2 | AM | Lec | Thursday | 9:00AM-10:00AM | 1 |
| 6 | Intermediate | 2 | C2203 | Comp | 2 | AM | Lec | Friday | 7:00AM-8:00AM | 1 |
| 7 | Intermediate | 2 | C2203 | Comp | 2 | PM | Lec | Tuesday | 3:00PM-4:00PM | 1 |
| 8 | Intermediate | 2 | C2203 | Comp | 3 | AM | Lab | Friday | 9:00AM-10:00AM | 1 |
| 9 | Intermediate | 2 | C2203 | Comp | 3 | PM | Lab | Wednesday | 3:00PM-4:00PM | 1 |

table Subjects

| subid | Sub | SubCode | Units | isLecLab |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Math | M2201 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | Science | S2203 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | Comp | C2203 | 5 | 0 |

[Added an image since table get messed up upon saving the post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOMvh.png)

But created a new table for this.

| subid | units | sub | UserCode | Shift | Sched |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | Math | M2201 | AM | Monday / 7:00AM-8:00AM |
| 1 | 3 | Math | M2201 | PM | Tuesday / 1:00PM-2:00PM |
| 2 | 3 | Science | S2203 | AM | Monday / 9:00AM-10:00AM |
| 2 | 3 | Science | S2203 | PM | Tuesday / 3:00PM-4:00PM |
| 3 | 3 | Comp (lab) | C2203 | AM | Friday / 9:00AM-10:00AM |
| 3 | 2 | Comp (lab) | C2203 | PM | Wednesday / 3:00PM-4:00PM |
| 3 | 3 | Comp (lec) | C2203 | AM | Thursday / 9:00AM-10:00AM |
| 3 | 2 | Comp (lec) | C2203 | PM | Tuesday / 3:00PM-4:00PM |
| 3 | 2 | Comp (lec) | C2203 | PM | Friday / 7:00AM-8:00AM |

I tried several queries and the closest I've got is this

| units | Sub | Code | AM | PM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Math | M2201 | Monday / 7:00AM-8:00AM | Tuesday / 1:00PM-2:00PM |
| 3 | Science | S2203 | Monday / 9:00AM-10:00AM | Tuesday / 3:00PM-4:00PM |
| 3 | Comp (lab) | C2203 | Thursday / 9:00AM-10:00AM | Tuesday / 3:00PM-4:00PM |
| 3 | Comp (lab) | C2203 | Friday / 9:00AM-10:00AM | Wednesday / 3:00PM-4:00PM |
| 2 | Comp (lec) | C2203 | Thursday / 9:00AM-10:00AM | Tuesday / 3:00PM-4:00PM |
| 2 | Comp (lec) | C2203 | Friday / 9:00AM-10:00AM | Wednesday / 3:00PM-4:00PM |

Second data for AM of comp (lec) didn't appear.
Here's the code I've tried

```
select a.usercode, a.sub, a.Units, a.am, b.pm, a.Schedid from 
    (select * from 
        (select distinct subid, usercode, sub, units, shift, sched from Table1 where shift= 'am') as src 
        pivot (max(sched) for shift in ("am")) as pvt ) as A 
inner join 
    (select * from 
        (select distinct subid, usercode, sub, units, shift, sched from table1 where shift= 'pm') as src2 
        pivot (max(sched) for shift in ("pm")) as pvt2 ) as B on a.shift= b.shift
```

Comment: Is use of the PIVOT keyword mandatory?

Comment: What about `select A.units as units, A.sub as Sub, A.UserCode as Code, A.Sched as AM, B.Sched as PM from data A join data B on A.sub = B.sub and A.UserCode = B.UserCode where A.Shift = 'AM' and B.Shift = 'PM';` https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5y3mTqaQKKnQEa2HGL54be/1

Comment: You should have mention that in your initial question.  Update your question, include the sample data together with the expected result for that scenario.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah for some reasons, it didn't work as i expected. only tried adding some rows in db-fiddle link you provided. :(

Comment: @Squirrel sorry about that. it just happened that i overlook some data while checking.

Comment: @CaiusJard not really. i just need to have the result the same as stated.

Comment: *Originally, I have 3 tables* - post their definitions

Comment: @CaiusJard   _"but created a new table for this"_ which i mean is that i created a new table where i will pull those data for easier coding but still cant figure it out.

Comment: Easier for you maybe (but then again you did embark on a process and get stuck..), but not necessarily for us; we can operate with your original 3 tables - post them so we have the luxury of deciding if to proceed with your merged table, or the originals. Making tables unnecessarily is a data management headache

Comment: In your desired output, why does Comp lec have 2 units, but Comp lab have 3? What is the logic that drives the contents of the Units column?

Comment: @CaiusJard will add the tables regarding that later. About the divided subject units, that's what is ask to be the output. Originally, it was 5 units (combine lec and lab). I, too, can't see the logic why was it divided as units for lec and lab.

Comment: I mean your lab has 3,2 as units and the lec has 3,2,2. Why does the output choose 2 for the lec and 3 for the lab? It's not consistently min, max, mode or any other pattern i can see. It looks like some exception for lec..

Answer (score 0):

Conditional agg will perform a pivot, and it's eaier to perform more advanced operations using it than PIVOT does, so it's a pattern worth learning.

To see how a conditional agg works, remove the GROUP BY and any mention of a MIN/MAX/STRING_AGG or other agregating operation. It makes it easier to see that a vertical arrangement of data:

```
  A, 1
  B, 2
  C, 1
```

Becomes diagonal when CASE WHEN'd:

```
  --CASE WHEN letter = 'A' then number end as a,
  --CASE WHEN letter = 'B' then number end as b,
  --CASE WHEN letter = 'C' then number end as c,

  A, B, C
  1, -, -
  -, 2, -
  -, -, 3
```

The GROUP/MAX then flattens the nulls out, so the "diagonal" data is fully rotated to horizontal

```
  --MAX(CASE WHEN letter = 'A' then number end) as a,
  --MAX(CASE WHEN letter = 'B' then number end) as b,
  --MAX(CASE WHEN letter = 'C' then number end) as c,
  A, B, C
  1, 2, 3
```

In your requirement, using STRING_AGG allows multiple values per cell rather than just one

---

This form is for use on your joined table because I cannot make assumptions about the 3 tables that generated it (no detail)

Something like this should work for SQLS..

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN Sub = 'Comp (lec)' THEN MIN(Units) ELSE MAX(Units) END as Units,
  Sub,
  MAX(UserCode) as UserCode,
  STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN Shift = 'AM' THEN Sched END, CHAR(10)) as AM,
  STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN Shift = 'PM' THEN Sched END, CHAR(10)) as PM
FROM
  t
GROUP BY
  Sub
```

..but it'd be good to see the source tables/the query that generated `t`. Getting the data in the exact order per cell (making sure that the cell says "Thursday..Friday" rather then "Friday..Thursday" might be really messy. It would help if these things were numeric/dates somewhere. Post the original data so we can see if it helps)

Comment: tried it and noticed an error "string_agg" is not a recognized built-in function name. it seems that it was for sql server 2017 onwards. I was using sql 2012. 

btw, thank you for pointing out my mistakes regarding my post.

Comment: Oof, that's a shame. STRING_AGG is usually done by some ugly STUFF FOR XML PATH in ancient versions of SQLS. Upgrade your DB or take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56575019/string-agg-is-not-recognized-built-in-function-name-sql-server-12-0 or for a look at different ways and their performances see https://www.codeproject.com/articles/691102/string-aggregation-in-the-world-of-sql-server

Comment: Incidentally, here it is working in a modern SQLS: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=68d6ced66bba61d35c82ede1aca15c79